# How do I build an exe in VS 17 Mac to run in Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I wrote a console app in C# on VS 2017 for mac, and the resulting build file is a .dll. I can run that fine in the IDE and from the terminal with "dotnet blah.dll".

What I really want is to give my little console app to my Windows friends who can then run it.

I'm not finding detail on the web or here on how to tell VS2017 mac to make me a Windows exe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a framework-dependent deployment assuming your friends have .net core runtime, they can also run with "dotnet blah.dll"

Otherwise you need to configure self-contained deployment using `dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64` command and some project configuration. More details are available at [dotnet publish MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x) and [deployment strategies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) overall

Comment: Thank you for the article links I will read them. I'll also give your technique a try, it looks pretty straightforward. I'll report back on how it went. Thank you.

Comment: I used this method, both with and without "--self-contained", . I get an exe (yay!), I also end up with a "netcoreapp2.0" folder with 218 files. these are the references to the "using." statements. I tried to run the file on a windows 10 x86 pc but I get errors related to "an assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (test.deps.json) was not found..".  

This may be stupid, but when I did C# on Win box, i just ran the exe. When porting from MAC, i just can't carry that EXE over?  Do I need to package all 218 files? 

I'm missing something here.

Comment: @user9245487 I think you need to deploy exe file and folder with those dll's. If I understand you want single .exe file. While I haven't done that personally, it looks like CoreRT is what you need, take a look at this discussion https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/13329

Comment: @user9245487 Previously when using classic .net runtime you got single .exe file with no system dll dependencies, because it relied on the fact .Net is already installed on machine (and it is with Windows updates), so sending single .exe just worked. With .Net Core you either expect Core is installed and your customers can run `dotnet yourapp.dll` or you need to bundle all libraries and .net itself with your application, that's why you got tons of dll's

Comment: This thread of replies is the best answer for me, and I understand why it's doing what it is doing. Thank you.

Comment: Thread is helpful. Had to copy all files 158 MB from Mac to Windows & it worked. Copies files once and as I made changes, copied only updated files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a runtime identifier in your csproj for Windows in order for a Windows-compatible binary to be generated. Similar for various Linux distributions.

A list of IDs can be found at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog. For example, to target Windows 10 x64 you would use `win10-x64`.

Once you have the csproj configured and have rebuilt you should see a win10-x64 folder in your build output that will contain the files you need.

Comment: Alright, that sounds like something I understand and can attempt.I'll post back to this question shortly with my results. Thanks.